# Nested foreach in knockout js not working with seccond foreach value

Tags: knockout.js, foreach

i have a model in knockout js with something like this:

```
var Model = function(model)
{
    var self = root = this;
    self.ObjectA = new ObjectA(model.ObjA);

    self.includeImage = function(image){
        self.ObjectA.Images.push(image);
    }        
}

var ObjectA = function(objA){
     var self = this;
     self.Images = ko.observableArray();
     self.ObjectB = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(objA.ObjectsB, function(ob){
        return new ObjectB(ob);  
     }));
}

var ObjectB = function(objB){
     var self = this;
     self.ObjectC = new ObjectC(objB.objC);
}

var ObjectC = function(objC){
     var self = this;
     self.ImagesC = ko.utils.arrayMap(objC.ImagesC, function(img){
         return new Image(img);
     });
}

var Image = function(image){
     var self = this;
     self.Key = image.Key;
     self.Value = image.Value;
     self.Url = image.Url;
}
```

And then, i have this HTML on a table:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: ObjectA.ObjectB">
<tr>
    <td>
       <!-- ko if: ObjectC.Images.length > 0 -->
       <div>
          <img data-bind="attr: { src: ObjectC.Images[0].Url }" />
          <button data-bind="click: root.includeImage">include</button>
       </div>
       <div data-bind="foreach: ObjectC.Images">
          <!-- ko if: $index() !== 0 -->
          <div>
              <img data-bind="attr: { src: Url }" />
              <button data-bind="click: root.includeImage">include</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /ko -->
       </div>
       <!-- /ko -->
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

The problem that i have is that the function includeImage, the parameter that i receive is not an Image of ObjectC.. the parameters is of type ObjectB.. why is that??
Its some foreach broken?

Comment: I cannot repro your problem. The `includeImage` gets an `Image` object as it should see http://jsfiddle.net/mMHA7/

Comment: That's weird.. maybe i have a small error on my code. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I just have found the problem! was a dumb problem and in the code of the question i forgot to include the thing that was giving the problem! LOL

I edited the code so you can see the main problem and was the first button outside the second foreach! of course that the root.includeImage of the first foreach doesn't work. 
I just fix the problem with:

```
<button class="action add" data-bind="click: function() { root.includeImage(ObjectC.Images[0]) }">include</button>
```